# Logstash codec rubydebug is not working

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-plugin

Installed latest version of Logstash in windows machine and tried to execute the below configuration .

```
"
input{
stdin{}
}
output
{
stdout {codec => rubydebug}

}"
```

output data is not showing the format. do u need install rubydebug plugin. how can u install in windows? what is the command to execute ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Configure file:logstash-simple.conf** in logstash directory

```
input { stdin { } }
output {
  elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

then run the following command from windows(my case)

```
bin\logstash.bat -f logstash-simple.conf
```

Comment: Why we need elasticsearch ? can you please provide more light on this

Comment: After updating with .conf file, the output is 2018-04-02T13:39:17.620Z helpmetolearn-machine Hello world .. output format not expected one. i am expecting @Version ,host ,timestamp fileds

Comment: If you are using elasticsearch , then the above configuration, If you are not using elasticsearch , you can skip the line.